# Solve $A\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4b}]=\exp[-(x-2)^2]-\exp[(x+2)^2]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The function $\theta(x,t)$ obeys the diffusion equation
>   $$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial
>  x^2}$$ Find by substitution solutions of the form
>   $\theta(x,t)=f(t)\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4(t+b)}]$ where $a$ and $b$ are
>   arbitrary constants and $f$ is a function to be determined.
>
> Hence find a solution which satisfies the initial condition
>   $\theta(x,0)=\exp[-(x-2)^2]-\exp[(x+2)^2]$.

Now for the first part I simply substituted $\theta(x,t)=f(t)\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4(t+b)}]$ and plugged it into the given equation and eventually arrived at $f'(t)+\frac1{2(t+b)^2}f(t)=0$, taking an integrating factor of $exp[\frac{\arctan(\frac tb)}{2b}]$ (that's $\arctan(t/b)$ it looks a little small there) and solved to obtain $f(t)=Aexp[-\frac{\arctan(\frac tb)}{2b}]$ where A is some constant. So that $\theta(x,t)=A\exp[-\frac{\arctan(\frac tb)}{2b}]\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4(t+b)}]$.

I can't really get anywhere on the second part, I've set $t=0$ so that I have $\theta(x,0)=A\exp[0]\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4(0+b)}]=A\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4b}]$ and by the initial condition given $A\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4b}]=\exp[-(x-2)^2]-\exp[(x+2)^2]$ and I can't get anywhere from here, in fact I'm now almost convinced this has no solution.

I have just seen that this question has been asked before, but no full solution was given and the other person who asked this question took a different route.

Hopefully it's ok to ask again, as I'm struggling on a different part of the question.

Many thanks.

Comment: The solution to the ODE does not have the $\arctan$. It would if it would read $\frac{1}{b^2+t^2}$. But as the denominator is $(b+t)^{-2}$ it is $e^{\frac{1}{2}(t+b)^{-1}}$

Comment: Oh yeah, I've just looked and between lines of working it turns from $\frac 1{(b+t)^2}$ to $\frac 1{b^2+t^2}$. Well thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help. Let me know if now the second part works out fine, now :)

Comment: Actually, although I've only been working on it for a few minuted now (since correcting it) I' still having trouble as I obtain $Ae^{\frac{2-(x+a)^2}{4b}=e^{-(x-2)^2}-e^{(x+2)^2}$ and I don't know how to solve equations of this form. So in honesty some more guidance would be appreciated. Thanks once again.

Comment: I have no idea why it not showing the equation properly, it should be $exp((2-(x+a)^2)/4b)=exp(-(x-2)^2)-exp(-(x+2)^2)$

Comment: It is not rendering because the first \e^{ is missing a closing } before the =

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43435/discussion-between-b00n-het-and-user307463).

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in chat. The solution for the constants $a,b$ is
$$f_{a,b}(t)=C_{a,b}\exp[\frac{1}{2(t+b)}].$$
So, as you said,evaluating the product at $0$ we obtain
$$\theta_{a,b}(x,0)=C_{a,b}\exp[\frac{1}{2b}]\cdot\exp[\frac{-(x+a)^2}{4b}]=C_{a,b}\cdot\exp[\frac{2-(x+a)^2}{4b}].$$
Now we note that the PDE is linear, so that the sum of two solutions will again be a solution. Hence to satisfy the initial condition, we compare
$$C_{a_1,b_1}\cdot\exp[\frac{2-(x+a_1)^2}{4b_1}]+C_{a_2,b_2}\cdot\exp[\frac{2-(x+a_2)^2}{4b_2}]= \exp[-(x-2)^2]-\exp[(x+2)^2].$$
Choosing $(a_1,b_1,C_{a_1,b_1})=(-2,1/4,e^{-2})$ and $(a_2,b_2,C_{a_2,b_2})=(2,-1/4,-e^{2})$ solves this equation. Now plug these constants back into $\theta_{a,b}$ to get the solution.

Remark: the above is indeed the unique solution because the $\theta_{a,b}$ are linearly independent.